# typesafe Children toArray helper props when mapping

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code where I use `Children.toArray` to then filter the children passed to the component

```
export function Nav({
  children,
}: MenuProps): JSX.Element {
  const desktopItems = useMemo(
    () =>
      Children.toArray(children.props.children)
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        .filter((m: any) => m.props.display === 'Always')
        .map((m) => <>{m}</>),
    [children.props.children],
  );
```

The problem is that I'm casting the element to any in the predicate passed to the filter function.

Can I somehow make this type safe?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that generally the `children` type is considered opaque in that it could be an array or string literal or an element etc.

If you know what type `children` will be, rather than chaining the `filter` you could assign the  result of `toArray` to a typed variable.

```
export function Nav({
      children,
    }: MenuProps): JSX.Element {
      const desktopItems = useMemo(
        () => {

          const childrenArray: typeA[] | typeB[] = Children.toArray(children.props.children);
          return childrenArray
            .filter((m: typeA | typeB) => m.props.display === 'Always')
            .map((m) => <>{m}</>);
            
        }, [children.props.children]
      );
```

I think you could also just use map:

```
Children.map(children.props.children, (child: typeA | typeB) => child)
      .filter((m: typeA | typeB) => m.props.display === 'Always')
      .map((m) => <>{m}</>);
```